# Use Siri to play all songs (shuffled) in iOS 9

Tags: siri, music.app, ios

In iOS 8.4 and below, I could tell Siri, "play all songs, shuffled" or "shuffle all songs" no matter where in the OS I was. But now when I try that, Siri tells me that I must be in the Music app, playing a song for that command to work. And even when I am in the Music app, it only shuffles the songs in the current album or playlist.

Does anyone know how to tell Siri to "play all songs (shuffled)" in iOS 9?

Answer (score 2):

"Siri, shuffle all my music" - that worked for me!